# Excel VBA import multiple matches into different columns same row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to import cells from another wb. So if cell in wb1 col H matches cell in wb2 col K then wb1 col k and L = wb2 col C and E in match row. Now there may be several matches so I want it to offset to the next column. m and n for next set, o and p for next, and so on.

This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rcell As Range, sValue As String
Dim lcol As Long, cRow As Long
Dim dRange As Range, sCell As Range
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim CurrentRow As Integer


Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws2 = Workbooks("Workbook2").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Sheet1LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("H2:H50000").Value 'Search criteria column
Sheet2LastRow = Workbooks("Workbook2").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Where to look for matches

 With Workbooks("Workbook2").Worksheets("Sheet1")
     For j = 1 To Sheet1LastRow
         For i = 1 To Sheet2LastRow        
             If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("H").Value =  ws2.Cells(i, 11).Value Then
                 ws2.Cells(i, 11).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("C").Value
                 ws2.Cells(i, 12).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("E").Value
             End If
             If InStr(1, ws2.Cells.Value, ws1.Cells.Value) And     Trim(ws1.Cells.Value) <> "" Then
                 rcell.Offset(0, lcol).Value = ws2.Cells.Offset(0, 2).Value
                 lcol = lcol + 1
             End If
         Next i
     Next j
 End With

End Sub
```

This doesn't work. I basically gave up since I don't know what I'm missing.

I looked for something like this but only found something a `Vlookup` or `Match` could do.

Comment: I honestly can't follow your wording, maybe you add some examples

Comment: Yeah I can understand why..  So lets say wb.("One").Worksheets("Puppies").range("H") has puppy names. wb.("Two").Worksheets("Growth Chart").range("J") has puppy names. So if there is a match then take their weight (col C) and height (col E) from ("Growth Chart") and insert it into wb1 col K for weight and col L for height. With multiple puppies having the same name I'm trying to place the other matches in the next two columns but same row. Not sure how else to explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by keeping track of an offset that you shift by two after each match copied. I'll track this in a variable called `offs`.
Also I suppose that the copying goes *from wb2 to wb1* as described in the text, not as "suspected" in the code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim cel1 As Range, cel2 As Range
    For Each cel1 In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").UsedRange.Columns("H").Cells
        Dim offs As Long: offs = 3 ' <-- Initial offset, will increase by 2 after each match
        For Each cel2 In Workbooks("Workbook2").Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns("K").Cells
            If cel1.Value = cel2.Value Then
                cel1.offset(, offs).Value = cel2.offset(, -8).Value ' <- wb2(C) to wb1(K)
                cel1.offset(, offs + 1).Value = cel2.offset(, -6).Value ' <- wb2(E) to wb1(L)
                offs = offs + 2 ' <-- now shift the destination column by 2 for next match
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is really close and can get me pointed in the right direction. This gives me an rt error 13 on "If cel1.Value = cel2.Value Then"   But you were correct on your assumptions.

Comment: Got it. We need the trailing `.Cells` in the `For Each` statements. Pretty sure about it. Basically we were comparing columns not individual cells, --> type mismatch.

Comment: That would do it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How would you avoid duplicate data? I'm assuming comparing the offset but I'm not sure how I would go about this.

Comment: Hi @Noisewater. I think that this should the subject of an entirely new question, and it will surely get comprehensive answers. This of posting your updated code and ask about the specific duplicate issue.